# Change color of non-transparent parts of png in PHP

Tags: php

I want to fill the png non transparent part with any color or image using php.

Following is the base image

[image: transparent cat]

Following is the target image

[image: colored cat]

I have used following code of php to fill non transparent part of the png.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/cat_1.png');
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

But it gives me following output.

[image: wrong output of cat]

please help me to complete my task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save this version of the base image:

[image: Base image]

This image has been saved as an indexed-PNG format, making it perfect for colour substitution. In this case, index 0 is the cat's colour, and index 1 is the background (not ideal, but that's what GIMP gave me)

In this case:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("cat_1.png");
imagecolorset($img,0, 255,0,0);
imagepng($img); // output red cat
```

Image editing in general is made much easier if you have a base image that lends itself to easy editing in this way ;)

Comment: Do you know how can I apply pattern image instead of red color?

Comment: Not nearly as easily, but you can use more than just two colours in the pattern you want and change those colours dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

This line `imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);` fills the image with the color red, at the coordinate (0,0), which is topleft. So it starts filling at the top left and fills everything like when you use the paintbucket in MSPaint. You could use `imagefill($im, 150, 150, $red);` for example (if 150,150 is the center).

Answer (score 0):

use this function, it returns a base64 image `<img src="output">`

```
public static function colorImage($url, $hex = null, $r = null, $g = null, $b = null)
{

    if ($hex != null) {
        $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);
        $r = hexdec(substr($hex, 0, 2));
        $g = hexdec(substr($hex, 2, 2));
        $b = hexdec(substr($hex, 4, 2));
    }
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($url);
    imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($im, true);

    if (imageistruecolor($im)) {
        $sx = imagesx($im);
        $sy = imagesy($im);
        for ($x = 0; $x < $sx; $x++) {
            for ($y = 0; $y < $sy; $y++) {
                $c = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
                $a = $c & 0xFF000000;
                $newColor = $a | $r << 16 | $g << 8 | $b;
                imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $newColor);
            }
        }
    }
    ob_start();

    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    $image_data = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    $image_data_base64 = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($image_data);

    return $image_data_base64;
}
```